# Unique identifier for a connection in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I would like to obtain a unique identifier for every connection established to Tomcat. I am not talking about sessions or uniqueness of users (clients) but every connection. Say, client A sends one GET, then another. In my scenario these are two separate and unique connections.

Is there any variable or something that can play identifier role for such a connection in Tomcat ?

Comment: Do you really mean connection (i.e. multiple requests on the same connection using HTTP keep-alive get the same ID) or do you mean per HTTP request?

Comment: They are almost certainly not separate connections, and they almost certainly share the same session. If you want to number individual requests, say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a ServletFilter:

```
public class UniqueRequestFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String requestID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        //save to ThreadLocal...

        try {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        finally {
            //remove from ThreadLocal
        }
    }


    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

You will be able to get the request value from the ThreadLocal at any point in your application.

Comment: It would also make a lot of sense to put the request-id into the request *attributes*.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet container has session tracking mechanism, usually its cookie with name "JSESSIONID", you can use it as session identifier.
From servlet specification:

The standard name of the session tracking cookie must be JSESSIONID,
which must be supported by all 3.0 compliant containers

More details can be found in servlet specification.

Comment: This is useful, but a new JSESSIONID would need to be generated for "every connection" if it were to be considered as a solution. Is this possible, or does Tomcat provide a file-based session cache by default. Can sessions be turned off while still generating the JSESSIONID?

Answer (score 0):

Jakarta Servlet 6.0 (c. 2022) adds a new method to the [`ServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/servletrequest) interface: [`getRequestId`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/servletrequest#getRequestId()).

While you may have had to write your own request-id-generator in the past, you should now be able to rely on a container-agnostic feature in your web applications.

Answer (score -1):

One solution could perhaps be to create a new session on every request?

A way to achieve that would be to set true in session-config/cookie-config in web.xml (unless you are running a HTTPS connection)